# Binding a sum grid value to a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

`enter code here`I have the following function that adds up the total for a specific column in a grid. How do I access the highestGB in an independent textbox through asp?
I have tried this, but with no success.
**Discovery Jobs**' >
Can anyone shed a little light, thanks.

```
double highestGB = 0;

protected void grd_JobTypeJT_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridFooterItem)
    {
        footerItem["GB"].Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Total: <br/>" + highestGB));
    }
    else if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

    string GB = dataItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[dataItem.ItemIndex]["GB"].ToString();
    double gbValue = Double.Parse(GB);
    totalPrice += gbValue;

    if (highestGB == 0 || highestGB < gbValue)
    {
        highestGB = gbValue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have what looks like a page level variable `highestGB` so assign it to the `Text` property of the `TextBox` in the `Page_Load` event handler'

```
txtHighestGB.Text = highestGB.ToString();
```